# ASP.NET - Does streaming file to the client occupy server memory?

Tags: asp.net, download, filestream, fileserver, tfilestream

I have a requirement to make the files in a file server available for download through an application running on a web server. Users would be clicking on the links available on the application page and a save as dialog would appear. This kind of a use case is pretty common and I might be talking about a basic thing, but I would appreciate if someone can confirm if my following assumptions are correct.

1) With files on file server, virtually mapped via a virtual directory in the web server to be accessible to the application (as links), it is possible to stream it directly to the client using content-disposition (with code similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020113/download-file-to-client-pc-in-asp-net-using-vb-net)), meaning without involving any code to process or chunk the file for the purpose of streaming it.

2) Since the file is directly streamed from the file server, the web server is in NO WAY impacted in terms of memory or disk usage (CPU would be used of course).

Thanks

Comment: It depends on how to stream the data. The method shown in that answer would impact memory while the file is transferring since all bytes are read in memory. Showing what code you are using would help.

Comment: I have not written any code yet, but intend to use the similar pattern show in the link I have shared. I am actually looking for a way where I wouldn't disturb the memory and disk usage on the web server when the files get downloaded from the file server. Are you sure that code would occupy "web server" memory? that suprises me. My understanding was since it directly gets streamed from file server, it may not occupy the memory or trouble the disk of web server. Thanks and appreciate your answer.

Comment: Actually, the link I shared uses the file from local "web server", but in my case I intend to point to a virtual directory that in turn points to a file server. In such case, the file server disk usage may go up (and may not be memory) but the web server disk or memory does not get affected right? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to write files directly and keep you memory footprint to a minimum, consider using [`HttpResponse.TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream,
>   without buffering it in memory.

This to my knowledge is the most efficient method to send a file in the response if you have to write it through asp.net.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName );
Response.TransmitFile(fullPath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I might have wanted to do. Thanks nunespascal!